# Header1 on website HTML5

Tags: css, html, header

I made a customer banner on word and I am trying to display as my h1 on my project.

website link:

http://younani.com/finalsite/contactus.html

I only implemented it in the contact us page, so the other pages don't have it. As you could see, its blurry and doesn't fit right. Even when I try to adjust the size and the image remains blurry.

Here is the code for h1 and I haven't included anything in the CSS for it, is that the problem?

```
<h1><img alt="flower" src="banner.jpg" width="1000" height="100" /></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your image is 674x194, make your width and height attributes match respectively, and it will not stretch the image.

```
<h1><img alt="flower" src="banner.jpg" width="674" height="194" /></h1>
```

Comment: Still looks a bit blurry, is that something I jsut got to deal with?

Comment: Save it as .png or .gif file type for that image, and you shouldn't have that problem. JPEG is better suited for photos, as it uses lossy image compression. Don't forget to remove the squiggly lines from spell-check/grammar-check!

Comment: That worked. It's not blurry anymore perfect! But what could i do to fit in header 1, like align it to the site?

Answer (score 1):

```
dont use  1000 width use 

<img width="960" height="100" src="banner.jpg" alt="flower">
```

Comment: let me try on your website using firebug

Comment: actually you need to make that image again in good resolution it is not in good resolution

Comment: In better resolution, as in different image type?

Comment: well jpg can be aslo used but use same size of image so it can be dispay in good resolution..